# Add our own application in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, popup

We have android device contains two different PDF reader application. One is `Adobe Reader` and another one is `Nook PDF`. When we have select any PDF files the `Popup Menu` is displayed. In this Popup Menu contains two PDF reader application. For example screenshot is

[image]

How do add our own application here (popup menu). When we have select any files automatically our own application has also displayed in the popup window. Is it possible.

New Screenshot is

[image]

Here `Hello World` Application Package Name is `com.hello` and `Exit` is used to exit the `Popup Menu`. How do add this two application through programmatically. Give me idea. I need example for some sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by using [Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ifs). You will need to specifically tell Android that your app is capable of handling certain actions, and then Android will add your app to the chooser for those Actions.

Comment: Thanks, But i can't understand where we will put our `application package name` and `application name`, how do add my application in `Popup Menu`. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Implicit Intents and specify them using [Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ifs)

It will look something like this. It needs to be defined in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
  <data android:scheme="http" android:mimeType="application/pdf"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

The action part says your activity will be able to view PDFs, the data part says it accepts data with the PDF type and with a URL that has an HTTP scheme. The browsable category is necessary to allow links from a browser to open this activity (optional).

Comment: Thanks, But i can't understand where we will put our `application package name` and `application name`, how do add my application in `Popup Menu`. Now i am edited my question. Thanks..

Comment: Application package name and application name will be specified while creating the project. And it will be present in your AndroidManifest.xml file. There u can go and change ur application name under the "application" tag - under android:label

Comment: `<data android:scheme="http" android:mimeType="application/pdf"/>` here how do add my `Hello World` Application and then how do add `Exit` Button. Really I have no idea. I have very bad memory. Can you explain How?

Comment: This might help u understand how implicit intents work : http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/implicit-intent-android